# Update component on updating state React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update my component on deleting an item, I've written the following code:

Profile.js:

```
class Profile extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.id = jwt_decode(sessionStorage.getItem('id_token'))['id'];
        this.getUserData = this.getUserData.bind(this);
        this.getUserAddresses = this.getUserAddresses.bind(this); 
        this.createUserAddressCards = this.createUserAddressCards.bind(this); 
        this.deleteUserAddress = this.deleteUserAddress.bind(this); 
        this.state = {}   
        this.user = new User(); 
    } 

    componentWillMount(){
        this.getUserData(this.id);
        this.getUserAddresses(this.id);  
    }

    getUserData(_id){
       var userPromise = this.user.user_data(_id);
       userPromise.then(
           (val) => { 
               this.setState({email: val.email,
                              firstName: val.firstName,
                              lastName: val.lastName});  
           }
       )        
    }

    getUserAddresses(_id){ 
        var addresses_promise = this.user.get_addresses(_id); 
        addresses_promise.then(
            (val) => {
                this.setState({addresses: val}, function(){
                    this.createUserAddressCards(this.state.addresses); 
                }); 
            }
        )
    }
    createUserAddressCards(_addresses){
        var addresCards = [];
        for (var i=0; i < _addresses.length; i++) {
            addresCards.push(
                <UserAddressCard 
                    street={_addresses[i]['street']} 
                    streetNumber={_addresses[i]['streetNumber']}
                    city={_addresses[i]['city']}
                    zipcode={_addresses[i]['zipCode']} 
                    id={_addresses[i]['id']}
                    delete={this.deleteUserAddress}
                />);
        }
        this.setState({cards: addresCards});
    }
    deleteUserAddress(_address_id){
        this.user.delete_address_by_id(this.id, _address_id);  
        this.getUserAddresses(this.id); 
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>            
                <Container className='content-container'>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <Card>
                                <CardBody>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col md={12}>
                                            <Button className='float-right' color='secondary' size='sm'>
                                                <i className='fa fa-pencil'></i>
                                            </Button>
                                        </Col>
                                        <Col className="card-row" md={12}>
                                            <img className='profileImage'  alt='Profile' src={logo} width={150} height={150}/>
                                            <Table>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Name</th>
                                                        <td>{this.state.firstName}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Surname</th>
                                                        <td>{this.state.lastName}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Email</th>
                                                        <td>{this.state.email}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Password</th>
                                                        <td>********</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </Table>
                                        </Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </CardBody>
                            </Card>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={8}>
                            <Card>
                                <CardBody>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col md={12}>

                                            <Link exact to='profile/add/address' params={this.id}>
                                            <Button className='float-right' size='sm' color='success'>
                                                <i className="fa fa-plus">
                                                </i>
                                            </Button>
                                            </Link>
                                        </Col>
                                        <Col className='card-row' md={12}>
                                            <Row>
                                            {this.state.cards}
                                            </Row>
                                        </Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </CardBody>
                            </Card>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Profile;
```

UserAddressCard.js:

```
class UserAddressCard extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <Col md={6}>
                <Card>
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardText>
                            <Row>
                                <Col md={12} >
                                    <div className="address-card">
                                    <b>Street: </b>{this.props.street} {this.props.streetNumber}
                                    <ButtonGroup className="float-right">
                                        <Link to={'/profile/edit/address/' + this.props.id}>                                            <Button addressId={this.props.id} size='sm' color='warning'>
                                                <i className="fa fa-pencil"/>
                                            </Button>
                                        </Link>

                                        <Button onClick={()=>this.props.delete(this.props.id)} size='sm' color='danger'>
                                            <i className="fa fa-minus"/>
                                        </Button>

                                    </ButtonGroup>
                                    <br/>
                                    <b>Zipcode: </b>{this.props.zipcode} 
                                    <br/>
                                    <b>City: </b>{this.props.city}
                                    </div>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        )
    }
}
export default UserAddressCard;
```

User.js:

```
class User extends API{
    user_data(_id){
        return this.get('/account/users/' + _id); 
    }
    add_address(_street, _streetNumber, _city, _zipcode, _id){
        return this.post('/account/users/' + _id + '/addresses', 
                        {"street": _street, "streetNumber": _streetNumber, "city": _city, "zipCode": _zipcode}); 
    }
    get_addresses(_id){
        return this.get('/account/users/' + _id + '/addresses'); 
    }
    get_address_by_id(_user_id, _address_id){
        console.log('/account/users/'+ _user_id + '/addresses/' + _address_id);
        return this.get(('/account/users/'+ _user_id + '/addresses/' + _address_id));
    }
    delete_address_by_id(_user_id, _address_id){
        this.delete(('/account/users/'+ _user_id + '/addresses/' + _address_id));   
    }
}
export {User};
```

API.js:

```
class API {
    constructor() {
        this.API_url = 'http://localhost:5000/api'

    } 



    /**
     * Sends POST request to API.
     *
     * var _endpoint  - (String) API endpoint (part after the base URL). 
     * var _data      - (Array) array that will be send to the server. 
     *
     * returns promise 
     */

    async post(_endpoint, _data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(_data)); 
        console.log(_endpoint); 
        let response = await fetch(this.API_url + _endpoint, { 
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(_data)
        })

        return response.json();
    }

    /**
     * Sends GET request to API.
     *
     * var _endpoint  - (String) API endpoint (part after the base URL). 
     *
     * returns promise
     */ 

    async get(_endpoint) {
        let response = await fetch(this.API_url + _endpoint);
        return response.json();
    }

    async delete(_endpoint){
        let response = await fetch(this.API_url + _endpoint, {
            method: "DELETE"
        }); 
    }
}

// Export API for global use
export { API }
```

Deleting an item is working but when I click the button the page is not rerendered. I don't understand why because on delete I'm calling a method which updates the state with new UserAddressCards.

Could anyone help me out ?

Comment: Can you add the code where you call `UserAddressCard` ?

Comment: It's the function CreateUserAddressCards, This stores the cards in a var "cards" in the state. Then I call the this.state.cards in the render @yuantonito

Comment: Is `this.user.delete_address_by_id` async? You call `this.getUserAddresses` in the next line and I assume it is before the address got deleted. But without access to the relevant part of `User` it's just a guess.

Comment: @pawel Added the code

Comment: @SanderBakker so like I have suspected. You call `this.getUserAddresses` before the address got deleted, because the deletion is async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your item is correctly being deleted but the page is not rerendered because you fetch the `userAddresses` **before** having finished deleting the `userAddress`

You should do the following:

```
deleteUserAddress(_address_id){
  this.user.delete_address_by_id(this.id, _address_id)
    .then(id => this.getUserAddresses(this.id));
}
```

Or if you have `async / await` in your project

```
async deleteUserAddress(_address_id) {
  const result = await this.user.delete_address_by_id(this.id, _address_id);
  this.getUserAddresses(this.id);
}
```

Note: It is not a best practice to handle components directly in the state. Basically your operation to add `UserAddressCard` in `this.state.cards`, you should instead write that code in the render and not store in the state.

Comment: When I use the first option React tells me this.user.delete_address_by_id is undefined. Second option not working..